# Is the slow waveform an alias - and why don't we see other alias'es of different frequencies?

Tags: fft, sampling, nyquist, aliasing

The following figures are data from sampling the DC bus of an inverter for a BLDC/PMSM drive running a speed-loop with FOC.
The upper subplots are FFT's of the signal and the lower subplots are of the signal.
The signal is measured in two system states: one where the inverter is inactive, and one where the motor drive regulates around a zero-speed setpoint. The PWM frequency is $f_{pwm}=10$ kHz and the sampling frequencies are as follows:

- Figure 1, 2 and 3: $f_{s1}=1.0\text{ kHz}$ , $f_{s2}=2.0\text{ kHz}$ , $f_{s3}=5.0\text{ kHz}$

[image]

- Figure 4, 5 and 6: $f_{s4}=10.0\text{ kHz}$ , $f_{s5}=20.0\text{ kHz}$  and $f_{s6}=30.0\text{ kHz}$

[image]

We clearly must sample above the Nyquist sampling rate to catch the PWM frequency of $10,000$ Hz.
However, the waveform of the 'alias' signal is so consistent - with a frequency of $0.08$ Hz !

A close-up of the FFT for the first four measurements are shown below to verify that the waveform has a consistent frequency. BTW, the DC frequency-bin is removed.

[image]

Finally, a figure for an additional measurement, with sampling freq $f_{s7}=200\text{ kHz}$ with a close-up of the waveform and the FFT is shown
[image]

I initially wrote this question to clarify whether or not the slow waveform in figures 1,2,3 and 4 is an alias of the $10$ kHz waveform resulting from the PWM colluting with a capacitor charge/discharge on the DC bus. After writing the question, I'm convinced that this is the case, but why don't we see alias'es of other frequencies ?

Feels like a stupid question, but is it possible for slow waveforms to get masked by oversampling ?

Comment: The 0.08Hz could be the clock difference between your the PWM clock and your ADC clock. Are your sample clock and PWV clock phase-locked ? If not, you will always see small frequency differences or drift

Comment: The data arquistion is carried out using a cDAQ National Intrument and the motor driver is from ST.  There is no synchronization between them.

Comment: I second Hilmar's opinion here. Additional thought on this: all the sampling frequencies you used are divisors of the PWM frequency. So any aliases generated by undersampling are bound to appear close to the DC bin, in this case at exactly the frequency corresponding to the clock difference.

Comment: Thanks - this is interesting... I'll investigate and comment on updated info